# go-pear.phar file error and unknown charachters

Tags: php, installation, pear

I want to install PEAR and I'm using PHP 8.1.0
I'm following this tutorial: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

The error is in the go-pear.phar file and I found it here: https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

And I have an error when I try:
php go-pear.phar
The error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'phar://go-pear.phar/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0\go-pear.phar:1284
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0\go-pear.phar on line 1284

My line 1284 and the following ones are:
[image]

Does someone know what I can do or where I've to search to solve this problem?